# Nextjs/React : Skip useEffect function on particular state change

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I built chart view page which display sales data.
This chart will updated through REST API when user change dimension, filter value and period.

```
useEffect(async () => {
   let [startDate, endDate] = getReportPeriod({target: { innerText: period}}) // get formatted date string
   getReportData(startDate, endDate) // function that call REST API to get chart data
}, [filteredDimensions, dimensions, dimensionTime])
```

Also, user can save and load chart setting.

```
const loadCustomReport = async(reportName) => {
   let res = await axios.post('/api/customReport/loadReport', {
      report_name: reportName
   }) // get report setting

   let setting = JSON.parse(res.data[0].report_setting) // parse report setting as json

   setRevenue(setting.metrics.revenue)
   setImpression(setting.metrics.impression)
   setClicks(setting.metrics.clicks)
   setCPM(setting.metrics.CPM)
   setCTR(setting.metrics.CTR)

   setDimensions(setting.dimensions)
   setFilteredDimensions(setting.filteredDimensions)
}
```

The problem is the useEffect function run twice(both of setDimensions and setFilteredDimensions) and response times vary, so sometimes I got report data that a setting is not fully applied.

Is there any way to skip useEffect function running on setDimensions?

I think put both dimension setting and filter setting on one state might be works but I just curious that there are other solutions.

Please advise me any suggestion to solve the problem.

---

@Gabriele Petrioli give me the solution actually I wanted. 
@man.in.the.jukebox and @Brandon Pelton-Cox's advice give me a great point.

Currently my code is as below(I changed before I saw @Gabriele Petrioli's answer)

```
useEffect(async () => {
        let [startDate, endDate] = getReportPeriod({target: { innerText: period}})
        getReportData(startDate, endDate)
}, [filteredDimensions, dimensionTime])

// button handler that add dimension to current dimensions state
const addDimension = (dimension) => {
   setDimensions([
      ...dimensions,
      dimension
   ])
   let [startDate, endDate] = getReportPeriod({target: { innerText: period}})
   getReportData(startDate, endDate)
}

// button handler that remove dimension from current dimensions state
const removeDimension = (idx) => {        
   let tempDimensions = [...dimensions]
   tempDimensions.splice(idx, 1)
   setDimensions(tempDimensions)
   let [startDate, endDate] = getReportPeriod({target: { innerText: period}})
   getReportData(startDate, endDate)
}
// load report setting
const loadCustomReport = async(reportName) => {
   let res = await axios.post('/api/customReport/loadReport', {
      report_name: reportName
   })

   let setting = JSON.parse(res.data[0].report_setting)

   setRevenue(setting.metrics.revenue)
   setImpression(setting.metrics.impression)
   setClicks(setting.metrics.clicks)
   setCPM(setting.metrics.CPM)
   setCTR(setting.metrics.CTR)
   setDimensions(setting.dimensions)
   setFilteredDimensions(setting.filteredDimensions)
}
```

Thank you all for give me great advices.

Comment: Can you post what is ```period```?

Comment: @man.in.the.jukebox period is the time period indicator ("last 7 days", "last 30 days", "last day" and etc...) which are parsed to startDate and endDate on first code snippet.

Comment: You call `setDimensions` and `setFilteredDimensions` only once, inside that function, synchronously. So, the next render should contain both of the updated values, and result in the effect running only once more.

Comment: Remove all the dependencies in the useEffect and just add period to it. ```useEffect(() => { ... }, [period])```

Comment: @man.in.the.jukebox I remove dependencies from the useEffect and put call getReportData function separate on each state(dimensions, filteredDimensions) updated.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I thought that too but it called twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your state updates are fired from an async function, react does not batch them by default
(*applies to React versions before 18, as in 18 all updates are batched regardless of where they originate*).

You need to opt-in to `unstable_batchedUpdates`, so

```
const loadCustomReport = async(reportName) => {
   let res = await axios.post('/api/customReport/loadReport', {
      report_name: reportName
   }) // get report setting

   let setting = JSON.parse(res.data[0].report_setting) // parse report setting as json

   React.unstable_batchedUpdates(() => {
      setRevenue(setting.metrics.revenue)
      setImpression(setting.metrics.impression)
      setClicks(setting.metrics.clicks)
      setCPM(setting.metrics.CPM)
      setCTR(setting.metrics.CTR)

      setDimensions(setting.dimensions)
      setFilteredDimensions(setting.filteredDimensions)
   });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the advise. It's really the solution what I want to know. =)

Answer (score 1):

By including `dimensions` in the dependency array for the `useEffect` function, you are telling React to re-render the page and execute the function in that `useEffect` block whenever `setDimensions` is called. Therefore, if you want to prevent that function from being executed when `dimensions` is updated, you need to remove from the dependencies array, like so

```
useEffect(async () => {
...
}, [filteredDimensions, dimensionTime])
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Currently, my code is just like that